# In a kubernetes Service, are the internal cluster IPs static across updates?

Tags: kubernetes

My gateway service does dns resolution once and then caches the IP address. For example, if I have a kubernetes Service called `service-a`, and the gateway routes to `http://service-a/`, dns resolution works perfectly. But if later the IP address for `service-a` changes, my gateway service would not notice, and keep sending traffic to the original IP address.

So: will the internal cluster IP of services stay constant, even if I change the service by changing its selectors, or adding an external load balancer, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the internal cluster IP of a service will stay the same unless you delete the service or manually change its cluster IP.